# Best way to perform filtering on view data in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

What would be the best way to filter records from a view based on tags in couchbase? I mean I understand that I can extract tags from the documents and use them as the keys using the map functionality in the view. But is there a way to select records from the view based on whether the record's key (which can be multiple values) contains a tag?

Example: I have a transaction that has the following tags (tag 1, tag2, tag3, tag4) and each view record (from the emit function) looks like this

emit ([tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4], null)

What I want to get is all the records that have tag2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: when I say tag2 meaning a specific value for tag2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions...  If the only purpose of the view is to find records with a particular tag, you could simply emit a view row for each tag.

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.tags) {
    for(var idx in doc.tags) {
      emit(doc.tags[idx], null);
    }
  }
}
```

This map function would give you rows as follows:

```
{"total_rows":13,"rows":[
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":"a","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_3","key":"a","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":"b","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_2","key":"b","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_3","key":"b","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":"c","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_2","key":"c","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":"d","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_4","key":"d","value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_4","key":"e","value":null}
]
}
```

When you query by key (e.g., key="a") you'll get the results for that key.  If however, your concern is "give me all documents where the second tag is 'xyz'" then you could emit the index as well.

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.tags) {
    for(var idx in doc.tags) {
      emit([parseInt(idx), doc.tags[idx]], null);
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, the rows would like like:

```
{"total_rows":13,"rows":[
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":[0,"a"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_3","key":[0,"a"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_2","key":[0,"b"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_4","key":[0,"d"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":[1,"b"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_3","key":[1,"b"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_2","key":[1,"c"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_4","key":[1,"e"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_1","key":[2,"c"],"value":null},
{"id":"foo_doc_4","key":[2,"f"],"value":null}
]
}
```

You would then query with an array key to get a key at a particular position (e.g., key=[1, "b"]).